# Getting JSON data ​​and put them in 3 different arrays

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i'm working on Android with Eclipse. I'm writing a project where my app receives (also sends) data from a mysql database. I wrote a php file to make the project to work. I'm using JSON to communicate with the php file hosted in my local server.
I don't have problems with the connection or similar problems but i receive this type of the json data:

```
   {"field1":"A","field2":"abcbab","field3":5},
    {"field1":"B","field2":"fakfef","field3":25}, 
    {"field1":"A","field2":"faefe","field3":12},
    {"field1":"C","field2":"aafefe","field3":30},
    {"field1":"C","field2":"caere","field3":30},
```

etc..

Now my Android app has the target to create three different arrays (one for the type A of field1, one for the B and one for the C) to subsequent processing from the JSON data.
I have two problems here.

I don't understand how to select a json value from a particular value of a field. 
I try to explain better, i know these instructions:

```
 JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);

 json_data.getString("field1");
```

But how to say: "if field1 is A then put the value of field2 in arrayA1 and field3 in arrayA2", "if field1 is B then put the value of field2 in arrayB1 and field3 in arrayB2",
"if field1 is C then put the value of field2 in arrayC1 and field3 in arrayC2". maybe I'm making it harder than it looks but i don't know i to do that.
In this way i have two arrays for each type of field1, there is a better way to get what i want?.
Remember: i can't change the code in the php file so the output that i get is always the rows shown above.

Comment: You must read every line as a different JSONObjects and then process every line independently. You can split your result (a String I guess) by the coma character. Then in a for loop process every token of the split as a JSONObject. Did you understand me? I'm so sleepy right now.

Comment: Can you give me a short example? Thanks for your support.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Sorry but i want to use methods with JSONObject and JSONArray on Java. It's not possible?